# Voltage reference for DAC: is a reference really necessary?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, analog, dac

In [section 10](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac101s101.pdf#page=23) of the datasheet for TI's DAC101S101 chip, it's suggested to use a dedicated voltage regulator only for this chip to reduce noise that digital circuitry could inject into the DAC's voltage reference.

[image]

My brain tells me that they're just trying to use an LDO as a low-pass filter.  Why not just use a ferrite bead or inductor to block the HF noise coming from the rest of my circuit?  Will this be less effective than using an LDO?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNVW6d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I imagine that an LDO would be **worse** because you're limited by how quickly it can respond to errors.  If your MCU is injecting noise at 50MHz + harmonics, you're probably out of luck in terms of LDO response.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend adding an inductor in your ground path; you'll have even worse ground bounce from digital interfacing

Comment: The regulator or reference chip will actually have more of a high pass characteristic than low-pass.

Comment: Even the 3% tolerance LP3985 regulator gives 50- dB of rejection at 1 kHz. A passive filter to do the same woild "be annoying" and an active one also annoying. [Datasheet LM3985](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp3985.pdf). Adding filtering to a reference source may help but excluding it is probably poor economy.

Answer (score 1):

> My brain tells me that they're just trying to use an LDO as a low-pass
>   filter. Why not just use a ferrite bead or inductor to block the HF
>   noise coming from the rest of my circuit? Will this be less effective
>   than using an LDO?

Take a look at the various graphs for ripple rejection and noise for the LP3985 and ask yourself if an FB or inductor will get anywhere near what the reference chip will do.

For starters, the LP3985 has an output impedance at DC of about 0.05 ohms and this rises slightly to about an ohm in the tens of kHz BUT, if you use a 10 uF output capacitor (or bigger) you will impose a much lower output impedance at those frequencies where the LP3985 is potentially weak.

How would this compare with an inductor or FB?

Output noise of the LP3985 is about 200 nV /rt(Hz) at 1 Hz and, ripple rejection is at least 60 dB at low frequencies / DC.

How can an inductor (of presumably moderate size) get anywhere near controlling noise and ripple that might come from your main power supply? What size of inductor could achieve this?

Most people like to use a voltage reference of course because you then have some kind of guarantee over what the DAC output voltage levels are. The LP3985 is a bit flaky in terms of initial accuracy and this is the only downside to using it as far as I can see.

Would that 3% accuracy be any worse than the accuracy and long-term drift of your main voltage regulator? Probably not and that is the scenario you get when using an inductor from that supply.

PS - don't put that inductor in the ground feed to your chip - it will cause more problems than any that potentially might be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your DAC or ADC is only as good as its reference. In your DAC101S101 case, the reference is also the power supply.

Remember your DAC outputs: (input digital value between 0 and 1) * Vref.

In DC mode, you'll consider the accuracy of your reference, its temperature drift, aging, etc. If you use the DAC inside a feedback loop to control something, then you won't need accuracy or precision. Same if you use the DAC to calibrate out an error somewhere: you do the calibration, and this zeroes out your reference's drift at this point in time.

However, if you want to use the DAC to output an accurate value then of course you will need an accurate reference.

AC noise is much more of a headache. If your supply comes from, say, a LDO like good old LM1117, and it powers dynamic loads which draw varying currents (like a cpu, maybe some LEDs which turn on or off, a buzzer, opamps processing AC signals, etc) then of course every time the current changes, the regulator will have to settle. Depending on the speed and magnitude of the current changes, regulator settling can take a while and output voltage can vary a lot more than you'd think from naively reading "reference voltage trimmed to 1%" on the datasheet...

Also the LDO has finite PSRR, so noise also comes from its input. If it's a switcher, then you also have HF ripple.

Now, if your 10 bit DAC is supplied from 3.3V then its LSB is 3.3mV. Just blinking a LED on your board will make your +3V3 wobble by a lot more than this. So your 10 bit DAC is waste of money, since you're only getting 7 bits out of it.

**Example #1:** A guy puts a load at the output of a DAC like yours. As a result, the DAC draws varying current from its power supply / reference. This causes the regulator to settle on every change of DAC value. Thus DAC settling times sucks horribly, instead of 5µs datasheet value it's 100x more. Solution, buffer DAC output with opamp, and don't draw varying current from a voltage reference!

**Example #2** Another guy builds audiophile DAC... feeds VREF input with output of LM317... insufficient PSRR of his regulator means there is 100Hz ripple on the output of course. Thus when testing with 1kHz sine wave, power supply spectrum is shifted up in frequency due to time domain multiplication and he's got peaks at 1100, 1200, 900, 800, etc Hz.

Answer (score 0):

Its more than that.  Regulators are not perfect: the output voltage changes with load current, even at low frequency and even DC.  Furthermore, the regulator only "regulates" the voltage at the feedback node.  In most regulator circuits the feedback node is either on chip or tied to the output near the package.  From there, you will have resistive and inductive voltage drops along the supply traces.  These are small and usually of no consequence as supply voltages.  An IC with a very strict supply voltage tolerance might require +/- 50 mV.  But 50 mV is 1% of a 5 V reference, which limits your ADC or DAC to about 7 bits accuracy.

You get rid of most of these problems by using a separate regulator as Vref, since that regulator will see a small constant load.  If you have substantial noise at 50 MHz, you will need to filter that with passive ferrite/LC filters as well -- typically before the LDO.

And in higher precision applications you would use a purpose built voltage reference which will only be specified to operate at very low current.

Comment: The Reference input on an ADC can be a very charge-spikey circuit, because of charge-balancing behaviors inside the ADC. Thus substantial bypass capacitors should be considered, on the REF node.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf: Indeed so. Capacitive redistribution ADCs are interesting beasts. See http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-931.pdf